# Getting "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" with Core Data

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, swift

I set up core data and am getting `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` every time the function is called. Here's the function:

```
func actionOnSwipe() {

var appDel : AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
        var context : NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

        var newQuote = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("KeptQuotes", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject
        newQuote.setValue("testQ", forKey: "quote")
        newQuote.setValue("testA", forKey: "author")

context.save(nil) 

}
```

I don't think the problem is `context.save(nil)' mainly because I commented it out and the app still crashed.

Thanks :)

Comment: Add an Xcode breakpoint on all crashes to the failing line.

Comment: @Moshe getting a Thread 1: Breakpoint 1.1 on ` var context` and ` var newQuote` :/

Comment: It looks like your context is nil for some reason. If you put a breakpoint between `context` and `newQuote`, then log out context, what do you get?

Comment: @Moshe getting a Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1001882cc)

Comment: Is `appDel.managedObjectContext` nil?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that ur context is initialized properly in the delegate.

Comment: I'm a newby - how would i do that? Thanks

Comment: Well, Take a look the code where context is initialized in AppDelegate.m

Comment: What would proper context delegation in AppleDelegate look like?

Answer (score 0):

By using the 'forced unwrapping' operator, `!`, you are inviting the runtime exception.  Generally, you should not force unwrap an identifier unless you know that the identifier is bound to a non-nil value.  Thus, since you don't know where the `managedObjectContext` is being defined, you surely should not be forced unwrapping it.

So, where does `managedObjectContext` come from?  The Apple Xcode templates include a 'Master/Detail project w/ Core Data' template.  To see it, go into Xcode, create a new IOS project, select 'Master/Detail Application', select Language: Swift, click 'Use Core Data.  Then examine the ApplicationDelegate.

The ApplicationDelegate has a lazily initialized `managedObjectContext` property. It is a bit involved in creating one as it depends on a Managed Object Model, a Persistent Store and other fundamental Core Data concepts.

Comment: My project has already has core data set up, and from what I understand managedObjectContext is initialized in the AppDelegate and it still doesn't work.

Comment: You've written a UIViewController that has the action `actionOnSwipe()`.  Rather than going back to the `AppDelegate` each time to access the `managedObjectContext`, pass the `managedObjectContext` into your view controller in the parent's `prepareForSegue()`.  This is the Apple recommended approach.  When you pass the `managedObjectContext` along; make sure it actually exists.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make managedObjectContext in app delegate. You can use a separate file to handle coredata related work. One possible case is that you are calling context soon after app launch. As, while app launch, database is setting up. Calling it later in view controller would solve this problem if this is the case.